# Error: An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback for Dash App in Python Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, plotly-dash

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J_Cy_QjG6NE) for building Simple `Dash` App. However, when I run below code, I am getting error that says:
 *"An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback."*

**Note:** I am running below code in `Jupyter` Notebook.If I exclude `debug=True`, then App runs fine. However, when I make edit to the app and save the edit, it will not render in app.

Please suggest work around for this.

**Code:**

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
html.H1(children="Hello000")
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

Ther are two ways: (1) In your code, set the debug=False, (2) set the use_reloader=False regardless of what debug is. In either case, it works fine inside the Jupyter Notebook:

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
html.H1(children="Hello000")
)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, use_reloader=False)  <---- Here
```

(Click on the URL it gives you, your app is running there.)